# How to clear a 'React boostrap-validation' form?

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form on a page where the form submit button is adding rows to the page - this operation can be done repeatedly before the page itself is finally closed

```
<div className="panel-body line-items">
     {/* A line-item row for each existing line item.  These update if they are typed in... */}
     {this.state.lineItems.map( (li, index) =>
         <LineItem key={index} item={li} } />
     )}
     {/* And a line-item form where we can add another one...*/}
     <CreateLineItemForm onSubmit={this.submitLineItem.bind(this)}/>
 </div>
```

The form looks like this:

```
const CreateLineItemForm = ({onSubmit}) => (
    <Form onValidSubmit={onSubmit} className="panel form-horizontal">
        <div className="line-item line-item-input-row">
           <ValidatedInput type="text" name="summary"/>
           $<ValidatedInput type="number" name="cost"/>
           <Button type="submit" id="createLineItem" className="btn">
              <i className="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg"/></Button>
        </div>
    </Form>
)
```

`submitLineItem()` on the form adds the line item defined by the `summary` and `cost` inputs into `this.state`, which causes a re-render with that new line item appearing in the `line-items` panel.

This all works the way I want, except that the form input fields ("summary" and "cost") are not cleared when I hit the button.   This means that those inputs always contain a "duplicate" of the newly created line item row, after the first row has been entered.

How can I clear these form fields (either as part of `submitLineItem()` or some other way)?

`<Form>` and `<ValidatedInput>` come from `react-bootstrap-validation`.

Comment: After some discussion at CV chat, there was not enough consensus that this question was unclear, so I edited rather than close and re-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself repeating a grouping of code over and over again, then that's usually a good candidate for a component. Why not break

```
<div key={index}>
    <Input type="text" name={"lineItem"+index} value={li.summary} onChange={this.onLineItemDescriptionChange.bind(this, index)}/>
   $<Input type="number" step="0.01" wrapperClassName="line-item-cost" name={"lineItemCost"+index} value={li.cost}
onChange={this.onLineItemValueChange.bind(this, index)}/>
</div>
```

For example:

```
   React.createClass({
     getInitialState() {
       return {
        someState: true
       }
     }
     render() {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
         <Input type="text" name={"lineItem"+index} value={li.summary} onChange={this.onLineItemDescriptionChange.bind(this, index)}/>
         $<Input type="number" step="0.01" wrapperClassName="line-item-cost" name={"lineItemCost"+index} value={li.cost}
        onChange={this.onLineItemValueChange.bind(this, index)}/>
        </div>
      )
     }
   })
```

If you're looking to reset the state of the form that initially holds the data, you could easily do it in the creation handler. You'd probably want to assign it to a button or something that gets clicked, if possible. You can also listen for a `return` keyUp I believe.

```
function handleCreateNewLineItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // if using a form element
  // update your state
  this.setState({
     li.cost: 0,
     li.summary: ''
  })
}
```

Into a component, give it either default props or an initial state, and then when you create a new one it'll be empty/cleared?

Comment: Interesting idea, which I will try.  But it's actually the ValidatedInputs at the bottom that are not clearing, and it's not obvious to me that they are created afresh on the new render?

Comment: Oh I think I see. If you're just using those as temporary containers for the data that'll be passed to the new instance of the upper part, then just reset the state at the end. I'll update

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, thanks for your help, and voted to close this question because it's not clear enough.   I will ask again when I find a way to clean up the code and make it clearer.

Comment: Sure thing. Another bit of possible direction: you could probably pass in an `addNewItem` function from the parent, give some state values to it, and then call it in the child component. That'd DRY things up and is generally a good direction to go

Comment: The [jury was out](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  on whether this question should be closed, so I just clarified it (maybe).   The problem is that the `ValidatedInput`s in `CreateLineItemForm` are not cleared upon submission of that form, and I can't find a way to "get at them" to clear them.

Comment: You can get at them using state; looks like they're bundled with the parent state right now, so you should assign state values in each value property and update that

Comment: It wasn't tilll I [read this](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/controllables) that your last answer clicked ... but ... now it works :)

Comment: Huzzah! Glad to hear it